# Actionscript 3 ExternalInterface, Pass variable to javascript?

Tags: actionscript-3, externalinterface

How would I go about passing a variable to a javascript function using ExternalInterface?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the doc for external interface call function [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29)

Ex.:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
if (ExternalInterface.available){
    ExternalInterface.call("myJavascriptFunction", argument1, .., argumentN);
}
```